# Jmeter - My response has multiple values of same id. I want to extract and pass these values incrementally to the next request

Tags: jmeter

My response to a save action is somewhat like this-
"diagnosisId":45686,"confidence":0.0, --other text--
"diagnosisId":45966,"confidence":0.0,--other text-- etc. Say there are 27 diagnosis Ids.

Now i want to send request for the 1st Diagnosis Id in loop till the last id (multiple records/rows to save depending upon the diagnosis Ids).
Request is something like this -
"diagnosisId":45686,"confidence":0," etc.

I have extracted the Diagnosis Id using Regular Expression extractor and matched the first value -
"diagnosisId":(.+?),

How do I pass the values incrementally now?

Comment: Check https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html Maybe something like `${__intSum(1,${MYVAR},MYVAR)}` will work or __BeanShell

Answer (score 0):

Given you provide "Match No:" as `-1` in the Regular Expression Extractor:

[image]

You will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as the result (viewable via [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)):

[image]

At this stage you can add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and configure it like:

- Input variable prefix: `diagnosisId`
- Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`

[image]

That's it, you can reference each consecutive ID as `${id}` in the request(s) which will be the children of the ForEach Controller:

[image]

Another example: [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/)